# pymunk space.gravity function

Tags: python, pymunk

I am trying to make a realistic physics simulator using pymunk library. The problem I am have is the units used in the library. For example, if I want to define the constant G for the vector Force, how do I do it? I already tested 9.81 using the command "space.gravity(0, -9.81), and it falls very slowly. I checked the pymunk references page but couldnt find anything.

Comment: If the speed is too slow, find the value which makes it seem more reasonable, then find the scaling factor and store it for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Pymunk by itself is unitless as described here: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/overview.html#mass-weight-and-units

> Sometimes users of Pymunk can be confused as to what unit everything is defined in. For example, is the mass of a Body in grams or kilograms? Pymunk is unit-less and does not care which unit you use. If you pass in seconds to a function expecting time, then your time unit is seconds. If you pass in pixels to functions that expect a distance, then your unit of distance is pixels.
>
> Then derived units are just a combination of the above. So in the case with seconds and pixels the unit of velocity would be pixels / second.
>
> (This is in contrast to some other physics engines which can have fixed units that you should use)

To validate this I suggest you make a simple test. Just make a body of mass 1 and let it fall for 1 unit of time, with your gravity and then check the answer:

```
>>> import pymunk
>>> s = pymunk.Space()
>>> s.gravity = 0,9.81
>>> b = pymunk.Body()
>>> c = pymunk.Circle(b, 1)
>>> c.mass = 1
>>> s.add(b,c)
>>> for x in range(10):
...     s.step(0.1)
...
>>> b.position
Vec2d(0.0, 4.4145)
>>> b.velocity
Vec2d(0.0, 9.81)
```

This is more or less the same as I get when I do the same calculation here: https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/calculator/free-fall/ (small difference since pymunk does calculations by steps, and velocity and position updates separately)